# adjoint of unbounded differential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

> Consider $T=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ as an operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with domain $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. What's the adjoint of T?

This is an exercise from Reed&Simon's book. I have managed to show that $(D(T),T)$ is densely defined, $ D(T)\subset D(T^*)$ and $T^*=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$. I am stuck on determining the domain of $T^*$. I am wondering if anyone could give me a hint?

Comment: If $f\in L^2$ and $f''\in L^2$ (in the weak sense), then $f\in W^{2,2}$ (why?). Conversely, if $f\in W^{2,2}$, then $\int f''\phi=\int f \phi''$ for all $\phi\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}))$ (why?).

Comment: Thank you! I have shown the other direction and the existence of first order weak derivative, $\int \phi g''dx=-\int\phi (\int^x_0g''(t)dt)'dx=-\int \phi'(\int^x_0g''(t))dt)dx$. stucking showing $g'$ is in $L^2$. Any hint for that?